# Get Data from WebSocket using VB.Net ClientWebSocket

Tags: vb.net, websocket, client

I wish to see a minimal example in VB.NET and without using any external libraries of a websocket client connection.

Like sending Hello to wss //echo.websocket.org and printing the result.

note: the suggested possible duplicate has wrong answers.

1) it uses a library (first answer).
2) The second answer instead confused sockets with websockets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i make a script vb.net websocket client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381158/how-can-i-make-a-script-vb-net-websocket-client)

Comment: no. 1) it uses a library (first answer). The second answer instead confused sockets with websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it so difficult?

```
    Dim ws = New System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket
    ' optional: ignore certificate errors
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, c, h, d) True

    Try
        Await ws.ConnectAsync(New Uri("wss://demos.kaazing.com/echo"), Nothing)
        If (ws.State = WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open) Then
            Debug.Print("Opened.")
            Await ws.SendAsync(New ArraySegment(Of Byte)(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ ""message"":""hello""}")), WebSockets.WebSocketMessageType.Text, True, Nothing)
            Dim bytes(4096) As Byte
            Dim answ = New ArraySegment(Of Byte)(bytes)
            Await ws.ReceiveAsync(answ, Nothing)
            Debug.Print("answer:" + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(answ.Array))
        Else
            Debug.Print("Not opened?!")
        End If
    Catch
        Debug.Print("Error.")
    End Try
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. It works but just for one time connection. How to make it standby to send and receive message to the server?

Comment: @frozenade just do a loop.. or put a callback or create an event..